# Loading Streaming Data from RabbitMQ to Postgres in Parallel

Tags: node.js, postgresql, parallel-processing, rabbitmq

I'm still somewhat new to Node.js, so I'm not as conversant in how parallelism works with concurrent I/O operations as I'd like to be.

I'm planning a Node.js application to load streaming data from RabbitMQ to Postgres.  These loads will happen during system operation, so it is not a bulk load.

I expect throughput requirements to be fairly low to start (maybe 50-100 records per minute).  But I'd like to plan the application so it can scale up to higher volumes as the requirements emerge.

I'm trying to think through how parallelism would work.  My first impressions of flow and how parallelism would be introduced is:

1. Message read from the queue
2. Query to load data into Postgres kicked off, which pushes callback to the Node stack
3. Event loop free to read another message from the queue, if available, which will launch another query
4. Repeat

I *believe* the queries kicked off in this fashion will run in parallel up to the number of connections in my PG connection pool.  Is this a good assumption?

With this simple flow, the limit on parallel queries would seem to be the size of the Postgres connection pool.  I could make that as big as required for throughput (and that the server and backend database can handle) and that would be the limiting factor on how many messages I could process in parallel.  Does that sound right?

I haven't located a great reference on how many parallel I/Os Node will instantiate.  Will Node eventually block as my event loop generates too many I/O requests that aren't yet resolved (if not, I assume pg will put my query on the callback stack when I have to wait for a connection)?  Are there dials I can turn to affect these limits by setting switches when I launch Node?  Am I assuming correctly that libuv and the "pg" lib will in fact run these queries in parallel within one Node.js process?  If those assumptions are correct, I'd think I'd hit connection pool size limits before I'd run into libuv parallelism limits (or possibly at the same time if I size my connection pool to the number of cores on the server).

Also, related to the discussion above about Node launching parallel I/O requests, how do I prevent Node from pulling messages off the queue as quick as they come in and queuing up I/O requests?  I'd think at some point this could cause problems with memory consumption.  This relates back to my question about startup parameters to limit the amount of parallel I/O requests created.  I don't understand this too well at this point, so maybe it's not a concern (maybe by default Node won't create more parallel I/O requests than cores, providing a natural limit?).

The other thing I'm wondering is when/how running multiple copies of this program in parallel would help?  Does it even matter on one host since the Postgres connection pool seems to be the driver of parallelism here?  If that's the case, I'd probably only run one copy per host and only run additional copies on other hosts to spread the load.

As you can see, I'm trying to get some basic assumptions right before I start down this road.  Insight and pointers to good reference doc would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with a test of the prototype I wrote.  A few observations:

1. If I don't set pre-fetch on the RabbitMQ channel, Node will pull ALL the messages off the queue in seconds.  I did a test with 100K messages off the queue and Node pulled all 100K off in seconds, though it took many minutes to actually process the messages.
2. The behavior mentioned in #1 above is not desireable, because then Node must cache all the messages in memory.  In my test, Node took up 2GB when pulling down all those message quickly, whereas if I set pre-fetch to match the number of database connections, Node took up only 80 MB and drained the queue slowly, as it finished processing the messages and sent back ACKs.
3. A single instance of Node running this program kept my CPUs 100% utilized.

So, the morals of the story seem to be:

1. Node can spawn any number of async I/O handlers (limited by available memory)
2. In a case like this, you want to limit how many async I/O requests Node spawns to avoid excessive memory usage.
3. Creating additional child processes for this workload made no difference.  The unit of parallelism was the size of the database connection pool.  If my workload did more in JavaScript instead of just delegating to Postgres, additional child processes would help.  But in this case, it's all I/O (and thankfully I/O that doesn't need the Node threadpool), so the additional child processes do nothing.